# Can not run projects grey run button - Intellij

Tags: java

[intellij image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1csb.png)

I cant run anything, how do i fix the grey run button?

Ive tried to add a new configuration but i cant add a main class

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder is not marked as src root. You can click on your src folder with right mouse button, find option "Mark Directory As" and hit "Sources root"
[image]